# off topic flags could point to sites Other than meta

Tags: discussion

well today we had a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23176/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-reference-link-error-for-a-static-member-variable) really suited for Stack over flow in gamedev. But when I tried to flag it I could only suggest it belongs to meta site. I guess we add Other related sites to that list, like SOF, programmers, or maybe mathematics.

side note: I just asked on meta.stackoverflow to add Gamedev to their off topic list, and some moderator said it only has enough space for 4 other sites which are already occupied. So I guess a moderator could do the job.

Comment: +1 Yes; this absolutely needs be addressed. I'm guessing it would take someone, somewhere about 2 minutes to add this into the off-topic panel.

Answer (score 3):

Just flag it for moderator attention.  We can migrate to any site.

Comment: I know, but it was nicer if other sites were in that list

Comment: +1 for "just flagging," that's what I do (pretty extensively) and it's much better, in my opinion, than bothering with links to other SE sites because inevitably we'll get a question that belongs on some SE site that we don't have direct links for, et cetera.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I'm sorry, but I totally disagree with this. There are _many_ questions here (eg. [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46539/c-collection-was-modified-where-items-are-not-being-modified)) that should go straight to SO, and some on eg. CS, Math, or programmers SE. Why waste mods' time when we can simply do it ourselves?

Comment: @NickWiggill As far as I'm aware, no amount of migrate flags will cause the migration to happen automatically anyway (especially not a year ago when I wrote that comment), so a moderator will need to be involved in any case.